Incompatible data types in expression or assignment
I am going to write an API on progress site (ABL), but when I try to compile it, I get this error:

Incompatible data types in expression or assignment. (223)
Could not understand line 77. (196)

and line 77 starts from here:
Assign AlertDetail.AlertId = Alert_Popups.AlertID
AlertDetail.AlertType = Alert_Popups.Alert_Type
AlertDetail.AlertUTCDateTime = if Alert_Client_Acknowledgement.AlertDateTime = ? then now else Alert_Client_Acknowledgement.AlertDateTime
AlertDetail.lTimeZone = lv_timeZoneDescription
AlertDetail.lTimeZoneoffset = lv_timeZoneOffset
AlertDetail.PropertyId = integer(Alert_Popups.propertyid)
AlertDetail.PropertyName = cPropertyname
AlertDetail.Alerts_id = RECID(Alert_Popups)
AlertDetail.AlertStatus = if Alert_Client_Acknowledgement.noack = "NoAck" then "AlertAcknowledged" else "AlertGenerated"
AlertDetail.Comment = Alert_Client_Acknowledgement.Acking_Text
AlertDetail.AlertAttribute = Alert_Desktop_Config_Details.Alert_attribute
AlertDetail.AlertDisplayString = ? /* to do: Initialize as a blob */
AlertDetail.AlertImageName = Alert_Desktop_Config_Details.Alert_Image_name
AlertDetail.AlertPriority = Alert_Desktop_Config_Details.Alert_priority
AlertDetail.AlertSoundName = Alert_Desktop_Config_Details.Alert_Sound_Name .

copy-lob from Alert_Desktop_Config_Details.Alert_verbiage to AlertDetail.AlertDisplayString.
copy-lob from AlertDetail.AlertDisplayString to ggDisplayString.

/* Replace variables with data */
run ReplaceVariablewithData(ggDisplayString, AlertDetail.AlertId, OUTPUT ggDisplayString).
copy-lob from ggDisplayString to AlertDetail.AlertDisplayString.

I expect the code will compile successfully in GUI procedure editor.

You are getting the error because the data type on the left-hand side of one of the assignments between the ASSIGN statement and the last "." is not the same as the data type on the right (expression on the left of = not the same as expression on the right). Each of those lines is basically its own assignment statement.
It's impossible to tell what the data types are supposed to be without seeing the definitions of the (temp) table and the various variables. In some cases, you get clues from their names - the logical fields start with l which helps - but that's not the case here.
The simplest way to debug this is to make each of those assigments its own line (add a period to the end of all of the lines), and see what fails when you try to compile it.

Your code sample is incomplete and your post doesn't tell us what any of the datatypes actually are. None the less, for debugging purposes, you could narrow down the error by replacing the bulk ASSIGN with individual assignments like so:
AlertDetail.AlertId = Alert_Popups.AlertID.
AlertDetail.AlertType = Alert_Popups.Alert_Type.
AlertDetail.AlertUTCDateTime = if Alert_Client_Acknowledgement.AlertDateTime = ? then now else Alert_Client_Acknowledgement.AlertDateTime.
AlertDetail.lTimeZone = lv_timeZoneDescription.
AlertDetail.lTimeZoneoffset = lv_timeZoneOffset.
AlertDetail.PropertyId = integer(Alert_Popups.propertyid).
AlertDetail.PropertyName = cPropertyname.
AlertDetail.Alerts_id = RECID(Alert_Popups).
AlertDetail.AlertStatus = if Alert_Client_Acknowledgement.noack = "NoAck" then "AlertAcknowledged" else "AlertGenerated"
AlertDetail.Comment = Alert_Client_Acknowledgement.Acking_Text.
AlertDetail.AlertAttribute = Alert_Desktop_Config_Details.Alert_attribute.
AlertDetail.AlertDisplayString = ?. /* to do: Initialize as a blob */
AlertDetail.AlertImageName = Alert_Desktop_Config_Details.Alert_Image_name.
AlertDetail.AlertPriority = Alert_Desktop_Config_Details.Alert_priority.
AlertDetail.AlertSoundName = Alert_Desktop_Config_Details.Alert_Sound_Name.

IOW remove the ASSIGN and put a "." at the end of each line. That will tell you which specific line is causing the problem. (Once you figure it out go back to the bulk ASSIGN, it has performance advantages.)
Looking at it, without knowing the actual datatypes defined in the tables, I think the most likely candidate is that RECID(alert_popups) is not compatible with alerts_id - guessing that alerts_id is an INTEGER or INT64 (you would need to wrap an INTEGER() or INT64() function around the RECID() that is the case.  Or, if alerts_id is a character field, you would need a STRING() function.
Having said that... you included those COPY-LOB statements below for some reason and they also look suspicious. If the fields in those COPY-LOB statements are CHARACTER rather than LONGCHAR that will also be an error. Although in that case the error should be "COPY-LOB only works on large object fields. (11285)"
copy-lob from Alert_Desktop_Config_Details.Alert_verbiage to AlertDetail.AlertDisplayString.
copy-lob from AlertDetail.AlertDisplayString to ggDisplayString.

/* Replace variables with data */
run ReplaceVariablewithData(ggDisplayString, AlertDetail.AlertId, OUTPUT ggDisplayString).
copy-lob from ggDisplayString to AlertDetail.AlertDisplayString.

